# Unexpected T_ECHO warning?

Tags: php, facebook, syntax-error

I get a UNexpected T_ECHO warning when I add the following line:

```
<div id="counter"><?php (function_exists('fbshare_manual')) echo fbshare_manual(); ?></div>
```

I'm not sure what's a T_ECHO and what's the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing an `if`.

```
<div id="counter"><?php if (function_exists('fbshare_manual')) echo fbshare_manual(); ?></div>
```

Explanation: `T_ECHO` stands for the "echo" keyword.  "Unexpected T_ECHO" means that word was somewhere it shouldn't be.  (Absent the `if`, PHP would consider the stuff in parens and the `echo` as two separate statements, and would expect a semicolon or something between the two.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need an `if` after that opening php tag.

```
<div id="counter"><?php (function_exists('fbshare_manual')) echo fbshare_manual(); ?></div>
                       ^-- Insert "if"
```